# What is the equivalent of this javascript object in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this javascript (I'm new to javascript so forgive me)

```
var data = [
            ['fff',   10.38],
            ['ddd',       56.33],
            ['ss', 24.03],
            ['ff',    4.77],
            ['dd',     0.91]
        ];
alert(data);
```

To me this looks like an array of arrays. and the alert gives:

> > fff,10.38,ddd,56.33,ss,24.03,ff,4.77,dd,0.91

I'm trying to create this in a c# Model - I've tried a lot but it never seems to provide exactly the same result.

```
alert('@Model.obs');
```

where the Model is:

```
//property
public object[] obs { get; set; }

//contructor
public EmployeeAbsenceChartViewModel()
{
    object[] obbs1 = new object[2];
    obbs1[0] = "rick";
    obbs1[1] = 3;

    object[] obbs2 = new object[2];
    obbs2[0] = "rick";
    obbs2[1] = 3;

    obs = new object[] { obbs1, obbs2 };
}
```

the alert for the `@Model.obs` results in

> > System.Object[]

This should be pretty simple but the javascript that uses the data object doesn't like what I return from the model. I think I'm, missing something somewhere...

so, how would I recreate the `var data` object in my c# model?

Comment: You can do this by using `anonymous types` in C#. Check this out:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: your json: array of array of object, or `object[][]`

Comment: You need to convert the value of `obs` to a json. e.g. `var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.obj))');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - perfect - that did the trick! Thank you so much

Comment: It kinda looks like looks like a `Dictionary<string, double>` if you need a specific c# type.

Comment: @BenKnoble, dictionay is more simple object in JS, instead array of array

Comment: Yes but its structure looks like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly write object to your View, it executes `ToString()` method.

In order to insert data in such format that JavaScript can work with it, you need to use JSON.

```
alert('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.obs))');
```

Note that `JsonConvert` is a part of JSON.NET library which you can obtain using NuGet. Probably, you can use `Json.Encode` native method - it should work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks - @StephenMuecke got there first in the comments but as you provided an answer you get the tick.